# Activiti and Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate-search, activiti

It is possible to use activiti framework with Hibernate Seach ?
İf so , How this could be achieved ? Do I have to write implementation of activiti classes or something else ? I am confused how this could be done.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
Activii is just a jar file that can be tied into any java application.
Do you want to use Hibernate search for business data or something else?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: I am trying to implement hibernate search for the data which is stored in activiti own tables . It is easy to use hibernate-search with our entites but I want to learn if there is a way to use activiti and hibernate search together ?

Comment: For example I want to use hibernate search to search Process Instance variables

Comment: Activiti uses the iBatis ORM for it's internal tables and therefore these tables are not really compatible with hibernate.

Comment: You can generate hibernate mapping from the current activiti tables, or implement your own persistence layer based on hibernate if you want to.
(one of flowable/activiti persistence impl http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2016/11/02/running-flowable-on-cockroachdb/)